# QueryDSL GroupBy and Sum

Tags: postgresql, querydsl

I have these QueryDSL statements:

```
BooleanExpression alwaysTrueExpression = match(null, null, datePeriod, period);

if (minAmount != null) {
    alwaysTrueExpression = alwaysTrueExpression.and(aggregatedOrder.totalUnitAmountWithoutTax.sum().goe(minAmount));
}
if (maxAmount != null) {
    alwaysTrueExpression = alwaysTrueExpression.and(aggregatedOrder.totalUnitAmountWithoutTax.sum().loe(maxAmount));
}

JPAQuery<AggregatedOrder> query = selectFrom(aggregatedOrder);
query = query.where(alwaysTrueExpression);
log.debug("sql={}", query);

return query.transform(GroupBy.groupBy(aggregatedOrder.tradingPromoterBranch.promoter).as(GroupBy.sum(aggregatedOrder.totalUnitAmountWithoutTax)));
```

But it throws the error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

I want to groupBy the aggregatedOrder by promoter and filter with amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I aggregate the column and filter by sum:

```
BooleanExpression alwaysTrueExpression = Expressions.asBoolean(true).isTrue();

NumberExpression<BigDecimal> totalUnitAmountWithoutTax = aggregatedOrder.totalUnitAmountWithoutTax.sum();
NumberExpression<Integer> totalQuantity = aggregatedOrder.quantity.sum();
NumberPath<Long> qPromoter = aggregatedOrder.tradingPromoterBranch.promoter.id;

BooleanExpression amountExpression = Expressions.asBoolean(true).isTrue();
if (minAmount != null) {
    amountExpression = amountExpression.and(totalUnitAmountWithoutTax.goe(minAmount));
}
if (maxAmount != null) {
    amountExpression = amountExpression.and(totalUnitAmountWithoutTax.loe(maxAmount));
}

JPAQuery<Tuple> query = jpaQueryFactory.select(qPromoter, totalUnitAmountWithoutTax, totalQuantity).from(aggregatedOrder).groupBy(qPromoter);
query = query.where(alwaysTrueExpression).having(amountExpression);

return query.fetch();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mixing two types of grouping supported by Querydsl:

- query.transform(...): groups result in-memory once data is fetched from database. In this case query doesn't cointain "group by" clause and transformation of data is executed on "java side".
- query.groupBy(...): add group by clause to your query. In this case grouping is executed by database.

If you need aggregation functions in your query, then you need to provide "group by" columns using  "query.groupBy(...)".